# how can i add_option as array from a form with just a text input

Tags: options

I have the following function:

```
function si_ad_call_models(){
    // title of the page
    echo '<h2>Add new ad call model</h2>';
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="add">Enter name of ad model: </label>
        <input type="text" name="new_model_name"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add your new ad model"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         add_option('si_ad_call_model', serialize($_POST['new_model_name']));
    }
    $myopt =  unserialize(get_option('si_ad_call_model'));
}
```

The variable $myopt outputs the first thing that i enter in the text field. The question is how can i add the values in an array and every time i submit the form it should update the option value? Is that possible?

Comment: is this really a WordPress related Questions?

Comment: why do you think this is not? i mean it's playing with the get_option update_option and those are wordpress related.

Comment: because its a more of a php question and not really a WordPress one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
function si_ad_call_models() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

        // Checking that $_POST['new_model_name'] is set is probably not enough validation.
        if ( isset( $_POST['new_model_name'] ) ) {

            // Get the stored models.
            if ( get_option( 'si_ad_call_model' ) )
                $si_ad_call_models = unserialize( get_option( 'si_ad_call_model' ) );

            else
                $si_ad_call_models = array();

            // Add the new model to the end of the models array.
            // @TODO Clean $_POST['new_model_name'] before adding it to database.
            $si_ad_call_models[] = $_POST['new_model_name'];

            // Store the updated array of models.
            if ( update_option( 'si_ad_call_model', serialize( $si_ad_call_models ) ) ) {
                // @TODO Tell user about success.

            } else {
                // @TODO Tell user about failure.
                // @TODO Log database update failure.
            }

        } else {
            // @TODO Add validation error code.
        }
    }

    // Title of the page.
    echo '<h2>Add new ad call model</h2>';
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="add">Enter name of ad model: </label>
        <input type="text" name="new_model_name"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add your new ad model"/>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

I did not fully test this code.